# python and objc bridge in an existing application

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I resently started programming in objc and I was wandering how can I use python code in an existing objc application. I found some threads in this site and some others but they didn't help me at all. What I want to do is to take the SpotlightAPI found in [apple's developer website](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SpotlightAPI/Introduction/Intro.html) and use the results to process them with python code. Until now, I've done the following: 
 1. downloaded the SpotlightAPI from apple 
2. created a new project based on the cocoa-python application template from PyObjc 
3. added the controller files from the SpotlightAPI to the PyObjC 
4. Configured the bindings the same way they where in the SpotlightAPI
5. Executed the program and all works successfully 
6. created a new python class file which inherits from NSObject (called python.py)
7. the python file has the following code:

```
from Foundation import *
import objc

NSObject = objc.lookUpClass(u"NSObject")
print "PYTHON VERSION BEING USED:"

class Python(NSObject):
    def sendit_(self, something):
        print something
        return "asdf"
```

8. I Inserted this code at the beginning of the Controller.m file:

```
@class Python;

@interface NSObject (MethodsThatReallyDoExist)
-(NSString *) sendit: (id) aString;

@end

@implementation Controller
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    Class pythonClass = NSClassFromString(@"Python");
    myPython = [pythonClass new];
    NSLog(@"Created PythonClass: %@", myPython);
    NSString * oneString = [myPython sendit:@"asdf"];
    NSLog(@"%@", oneString);
    return self;
}
```

9. added `id *myPython;` in the variable declarations in the Controller.h file

10. implemented the sendit method in the controller.m file like this:

```
- (NSString *) sendit:(id) aString
{

    return [myPython sendit:aString];
}
```

it compiles and runs successfully but the console message I'm getting from the init function is: `Created PythonClass: (null)` and also the string return of the next log is `(null)`

anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few questionable things in the code you've listed.  First,  you should have `id myPython` not `id *myPython` as id is already a pointer. Second, you are declaring a method on an NSString category but implementing it in a subclass.  Generally, you want to implement the method in a category implementation on the same class (NSObject in this case).  Third, its all a bit circular to have sendit as a method on NSObject, which when implemented calls sendit on myPython, which is also an NSObject.  I'm surprised it compiles and doesn't crash.  Try cleaning up these issues and see where you get.  Hope this helps!